# How to get data from url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get /1 from this url but i can't.

http://localhost/medical/common/nurse/search?nrs_name=&nrs_phone=&nrs_id=&nrs_gender=2&nrs_address=/1

Here /1 is the page no

Comment: why using /1 instead of 1?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$parameter = $this->input->get('nrs_address');
```

OR

```
$parameter = $_GET['nrs_address'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

```
$urldata = $this->input->get();
```

you will get all url data on $urldata variable in associative array (key-value pair) form. and you can use it like this one.

$urldata['nrs_name']

Answer (score 0):

if you have to pass the value you should enter url like this

```
localhost/yoururl/index.php/abc_controller/70
```

and in controller function you can get like this:

```
public function index( $id = NULL ) {
  echo $id;
}
```

**Reference:**

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html?highlight=get%20url#using-post-get-cookie-or-server-data

Answer (score 0):

Apply this code.

```
$nrs_address= $_GET['nrs_address'];
echo $nrs_address;
```